# Replaying page on iOS app

Tags: ios

I am making an iOS app through xcode for audits where each room in a building uses the same page format but has different information. How can I replay the same page over through an add bar button so that when the add button is pressed the same page comes up but with all the text fields empty.

Comment: create a new instance of your page class would seem the most logical approach.

Comment: Wow definitely over thought this, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume when you are done putting in the information, you must be saving the information in the local DB or any server may be.

What you can do is, once you are done with putting in all the information display an alert stating that the information is saved and upon the clicking on any button on the alert, clear all the fields.